# How to change email address for 'An unexpected error has occurred.' NetSuite messages

Tags: error-handling, netsuite

We recently had a third party bundle issue an error email for `An unexpected error has occurred.`

This email was sent to the person who originally installed the bundle and they are no longer with the company.

Need to change who it delivers to. Where can this setting be adjusted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

- The person that installed the bundle is also the person that is
  listed as the owner of all the scripts included in that bundle.  If
  you go to the script record that generated the error (Customizations
  -> Scripting -> Scripts), you can change the owner of the script and future error emails will be sent to the new owner.
- On the script    record that generated the error, there is an
  Unhandled Errors tab.     By default, this is set to Notify Script
  Owner.  You can change this    to be the owner, the current user, all
  admins, a NetSuite group or a    comma-separated list of email
  addresses.

Comment: Thanks, that worked out. A couple things: First it would be nice if there was a way to simply claim ownership of all scripts within a bundle as it was tedious to open them all and update. Second, I noticed some of them had updated ownership from when a different user performed an update of the bundle, however it was only for those scripts which were replaced.